# Obtain view attributes in a chid custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view with some custom attributes.

```
class SomeCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```

It is clear how to retrieve the attributes here:

```
val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SomeCustomView, 0, 0)
try {
    someAttribute = a.getInt(R.styleable.SomeCustomView_swomeAttribute, DEFAULT_VALUE)
    //...
} finally {
    a.recycle()
}
```

The View's layout is inflated with
`inflate(context, R.layout.some_view, this)`

The thing is that `R.layout.some_view` contains **another** custom view as one of its child, which shouldn't be exposed (`ChildCustomView`).

The question is how to retrieve the attributes, set for `SomeCustomView` inside of `ChildCustomView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve attribute from parent until the child view is inflated.

So you have to store them in ChildCustomView fields, and `onFinishInflate()` of SomeParentCustomView, retrieve them with property access or getter.